# Javascript with Jquery Mobile not working in Android 2.3 and lower

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an application but it won't give any response on user actions. When you submit the form you just get a empty page. The button Anoniem inloggen don't work either, both are created in javascript. This only happens when using *Android 2.3* or lower. I have tried a lot of solutions, but none has worked so far. Even the already given solutions won't work.

Link to the application: http://goo.gl/MsZfO.

The index script of this app looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) { 
    checkMail();
    $.post('stats.php',
            function (data, textStatus) {
                $('#stats').empty();
                $('#stats').append(data).page();
                $('#stats').page('destroy').page();

            });

            $.post('welcome.php',
            function (data, textStatus) {
                $('#mail').empty();
                $('#mail').append(data).page();
                $('#mail').page('destroy').page();

            });

    function checkMail() {
                    var item = localStorage.getItem('maillogin');
            if (item !== null) {
                window.location = '#stats';
                }
            else{
                window.location = '#mail';
                }
    }
    });
</script>
```

The index body:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="mail" data-transition="none">
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="stats" data-transition="none">
</div>
```

And here's the problem page (welcome.php) script:

```
    $(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('#mailform').submit(function () {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            var email = document.getElementById('email');
            var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#mail");
                        alert('Dit is geen geldig mailadres');
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                        return false
                    }
                else{
                if($('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
            $.post('mailinsert.php',
            $('#mailform').serialize())
                localStorage.setItem('maillogin', $('#email').val());
                $('#inlogmail').empty();
                $('#inlogmail').append(localStorage.getItem('maillogin')).trigger('create');
                $.post('stats.php',
                                         function (data, textStatus) {
                                         $('#stats').empty();
                                         $('#stats').append(data).page();
                                         $('#stats').page('destroy').page();
                                         $.mobile.changePage("#stats");
                                         $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                                         });


                }
                else{                       $.mobile.changePage("#mail");
                        alert('De voorwaarden zijn niet geaccepteerd');
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                        return false;
                        }

                }
            });
$('#skipright').click(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('maillogin', 'anoniem');
                $.post('stats.php',
                                         function (data, textStatus) {
                                         $('#stats').empty();
                                         $('#stats').append(data).page();
                                         $('#stats').page('destroy').page();
                                         $.mobile.changePage("#stats");
                                         $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                                         });

});
});
```

And the problem page (welcome.php) body:

```
<form id="mailform">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
<br />
<div class="ui-grid-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-bar ui-bar-b">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" data-role="none"/>
<label for="checkbox">Ja, ik accepteer de voorwaarden</label>
</div></br>
<input type="submit" value="Stemmen maar!"/>
</div>
</form>
<h3><a class="skipright" id="skipright">Anoniem inloggen</a></h3>
</div>
```

So in short the implemented actions from welcome.php like .click and .submit won't work in index.html  on android 2.3 or lower. How can we fix these?

Answer (score 2):

Try with changing your following line:

```
window.location = '#stats';
```

for this one:

```
window.location.href += '#stats';
```

**UPDATE**:
If you already have an anchor link loaded in the location (like `#home`) then do the following:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#')) + '#stats';
```

Comment: I have tried that before but unfortunately this doesn’t work. The buttons that are created in Javascript don’t work either.

Comment: I've updated my question with the real error. The error wasn't in window.location but in the user actions. No user action works on Android 2.3 and lower.