# Why does phonegap build javascript code (window.location.href="index.html#menu";) not working in Android 2.3 but working in 4.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
<button onClick="new function(){window.location.href='#menupage'}" data-role="button">Test Button</button>
```

is the code I am testing. I also tested creating a new function on js file instead of inline function.

The code works fine on firefox(desktop) browser and on Android 4.0 but not in Android 2.3

I am getting "Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge callback due to a bug on the 2.3 emulator"

Comment: Do you get an error in the console log? If not, can you test if it fires at all (test it with alert('test');. I can inmagen though that Android 2.3 is more limited then 4.0. It may be wise to leave 2.3 alone and focus on 4.0 and higher. Version 2.3 is shrinking hard at the moment.

Comment: Yes Alert is working
window.location.href is not working

Console says
CordovaWebView(9202): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge callback due to a bug on the 2.3 emulator

I dont know what it is.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to use jQuery (or other framework) for changing pages. Read more about the callback error here: http://www.jasonshah.com/handling-android-2-3-webviews-broken-addjavascriptinterface/

Comment: this might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564845/javascript-with-jquery-mobile-not-working-in-android-2-3-and-lower